# Abstract dataclass without abstract methods in Python: prohibit instantiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, abc, python-dataclasses

Even if a class is inherited from `ABC`, it can still be instantiated unless it contains abstract methods.

Having the code below, what is the best way to prevent an `Identifier` object from being created: `Identifier(['get', 'Name'])`?

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Identifier(ABC):
    sub_tokens: List[str]

    @staticmethod
    def from_sub_tokens(sub_tokens):
        return SimpleIdentifier(sub_tokens) if len(sub_tokens) == 1 else CompoundIdentifier(sub_tokens)


@dataclass
class SimpleIdentifier(Identifier):
    pass


@dataclass
class CompoundIdentifier(Identifier):
    pass
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can create a `AbstractDataclass` class which guarantees this behaviour, and you can use this every time you have a situation like the one you described.

```
@dataclass 
class AbstractDataclass(ABC): 
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs): 
        if cls == AbstractDataclass or cls.__bases__[0] == AbstractDataclass: 
            raise TypeError("Cannot instantiate abstract class.") 
        return super().__new__(cls)
```

So, if `Identifier` inherits from `AbstractDataclass` instead of from `ABC` directly, modifying the `__post_init__` will not be needed.

```
@dataclass
class Identifier(AbstractDataclass):
    sub_tokens: List[str]

    @staticmethod
    def from_sub_tokens(sub_tokens):
        return SimpleIdentifier(sub_tokens) if len(sub_tokens) == 1 else CompoundIdentifier(sub_tokens)


@dataclass
class SimpleIdentifier(Identifier):
    pass


@dataclass
class CompoundIdentifier(Identifier):
    pass
```

Instantiating `Identifier` will raise `TypeError` but not instantiating `SimpleIdentifier` or `CompountIdentifier`.
And the `AbstractDataclass` can be re-used in other parts of the code.

Comment: What about cases when `SimpleIdentifier` or `CompoundIdentifier` are also meant to be abstract (concrete classes are not immediate derivatives of `AbstractDataclass`)?

Comment: @z33k I guess you can use multiple inheritance so that they both inherit from `AbstractDataclass` too.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way I have found is to check the type of the object in the `__post_init__` method:

```
@dataclass
class Identifier(ABC):
    ...

    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.__class__ == Identifier:
            raise TypeError("Cannot instantiate abstract class.")

    ...
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you need to use initialized class variables inside `__init__`. You won't be able to catch the `AttributeError`